# How To Use non-staticHow “getSystemService” in Custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

In Android eclipse
When I Want To Use non-staticHow “getSystemService", it show me Error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContext() from the type ArrayAdapter

ArrayAddapter.java :

```
package ir.redreactor.app.Com.NovinEr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter<StructNote> {

public AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> array) {
    super(G.context, R.layout.adapter_notes, array);
}


private static class ViewHolder {

    public ViewGroup LayoutRt;
    public TextView  txtTitle;
    public TextView  txtSort;
    public TextView  txtTableName;
    public TextView  txtID;
    public TextView  txtpos;
    public TextView  txtDetail;


    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleAN);
        txtSort = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSortAN);
        txtTableName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTableNameAN);
        txtID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIDAN);
        txtpos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtpos);
        txtDetail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDetailAN);
        LayoutRt = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_Rt);
    }


    private void copy(String strdata) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(strdata);
    }


    public void fill(ArrayAdapter<StructNote> Adapter, StructNote Item, final int position) {
        txtTitle.setText(Item.title);
        txtDetail.setText(Item.detail);
        txtSort.setText(Item.Sort.toString());
        txtTableName.setText(Item.nameOfTable);
        txtID.setText(Item.intID.toString());
        txtpos.setText("" + position);
        LayoutRt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                copy(txtTitle.getText().toString() + "\n" + txtDetail.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    StructNote item = getItem(position);
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_notes, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.fill(this, item, position);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

StructNote.java :

```
package ir.redreactor.app.Com.NovinEr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;


public class StructNote {

public String  nameOfTable;
public Integer Sort;
public Integer intID;
public Boolean Favorite;
public String  title;
public String  detail;
```

}

G.java Is Global Class
Class G.java:

```
public class G extends Application {

    // Creating Context
    public static Context               context;
    // Creating Log
    public static String                LOG_TAG         = "RR1";
    public static String                LOG_ERR         = "NVR";
    //Creating Current Activity Finder 
    public static Activity              currentActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

When I Use "getSystemService" With Out "getContext()" It Show Me Below Error:
The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type AdapterNote.ViewHolder

------------------------------- Edit

thank You Raghunandan
So AdapterNote.java Will Be:

```
package ir.redreactor.app.Com.NovinEr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter<StructNote> {

public LayoutInflater mInflater;
public static Context context;


public AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> array, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.adapter_notes, array);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}


private static class ViewHolder {

    public ViewGroup LayoutRt;
    public TextView  txtTitle;
    public TextView  txtSort;
    public TextView  txtTableName;
    public TextView  txtID;
    public TextView  txtpos;
    public TextView  txtDetail;


    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleAN);
        txtSort = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSortAN);
        txtTableName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTableNameAN);
        txtID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIDAN);
        txtpos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtpos);
        txtDetail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDetailAN);
        LayoutRt = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_Rt);
    }


    private void copy(String strdata) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(strdata);
    }


    public void fill(ArrayAdapter<StructNote> Adapter, StructNote Item, final int position) {
        txtTitle.setText(Item.title);
        txtDetail.setText(Item.detail);
        txtSort.setText(Item.Sort.toString());
        txtTableName.setText(Item.nameOfTable);
        txtID.setText(Item.intID.toString());
        txtpos.setText("" + position);
        LayoutRt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                copy(txtTitle.getText().toString() + "\n" + txtDetail.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    StructNote item = getItem(position);
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_notes, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.fill(this, item, position);
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `G.context`? pass the context to the constructor of adapter

Comment: It's Defined In My Class Named "G.java"

Comment: What is G.java a Activity class??

Comment: My Global Class To Use Some Things I Need To Use In App, for Example : Context , Database , CurrentActivity , Log Tag And ...

Comment: follow my post it will work. i don't knwo what you are doing global class??

Comment: Is It Correct? I Edited In The End Of My Post

Comment: yes it is correct.  pass context to adapter constructor

Comment: @Raghunandan  can i have your mail? i have been blocked to ask question! i have some problems but there is no one to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the context to the adapter constructor

```
new AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> array,ActivityName.this)
```

Then

```
LayoutInfalter mInflater; 
Context context;
public AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> array,Context context) {
super(context, R.layout.adapter_notes, array);
mInfalter = LayoutInfalter.from(context);
this.context =context;
}
```

Then

```
 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_notes, parent, false);
```

Then

```
 android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

Comment: can i have your mail? i have been blocked to ask question! i have some problems but there is no one to help me